# Is there a better way of receiving data from a websocket server than ClientWebSocket in a client console application?

Tags: c#, websocket

I am trying my hand with Websockets to get data out from a particular URI.
From what I understand is that there are no Web API endpoints, just a single URI with various forms of JSON data coming through from the server side.
I was wondering if there is a simpler way of getting data from that endpoint beyond what appears to be raw websocket connections in my console application.
The data collected will be logged for processing later.

```
clientWebSocket = new ClientWebSocket();
await clientWebSocket.ConnectAsync(new Uri(serverSetting.KSimNetAPIServerUrl), stoppingToken);

while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    var buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[2048]);
    WebSocketReceiveResult result;
    String json;

    using (System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
        do
        {
            result = await clientWebSocket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, stoppingToken);
            ms.Write(buffer.Array, buffer.Offset, result.Count);
        } while (!result.EndOfMessage);

        if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
            break;

        ms.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);

        json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        _logger.LogInformation("Received: {0}", json);
    }
    // TODO: Processing of the JSON data
}
```

Comment: By "simpler" do you mean "higher level?" "Fewer lines of code?"  This looks pretty simple to me; at least you're not wrangling with IP addresses and routing tables.

Comment: Yup, possibly something higher level, if there is one.

Comment: Well. you could always wrap this code in your own class.